# Minikube hanging on Creating hyperv VM

Tags: kubernetes, hyper-v, minikube

**Heads up**: I need Hyper-V as VM driver because I want to be able to use the ingress addon; using Docker as the driver will not allow the use of addons in Windows.

I am using Minikube v1.11.0 and Kubernetes v1.18.3. When I am trying to create and launch a Minikube cluster according to [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/minikube-on-windows-10-with-hyper-v-6ef0f4dc158c) with Hyper-V in PowerShell it keeps hanging on 'Creating hyperv VM:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Primary Virtual Switch"
* minikube v1.11.0 on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18363 Build 18363
  - KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config
* Using the hyperv driver based on user configuration
* Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
* Creating hyperv VM (CPUs=4, Memory=4096MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
```

After about 10 minutes it goes further and crashes with this errors:

```
* Stopping "minikube" in hyperv ...
* Powering off "minikube" via SSH ...
* Deleting "minikube" in hyperv ...
! StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create host timed out in 240.000000 seconds
E0605 19:02:43.905739   30748 main.go:106] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
At line:1 char:3
+ ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM

...
Multiple E0605 errors
...

* Failed to start hyperv VM. "minikube start" may fix it: creating host: create host timed out in 240.000000 seconds
*
* [CREATE_TIMEOUT] error provisioning host Failed to start host: creating host: create host timed out in 240.000000 seconds
* Suggestion: Try 'minikube delete', and disable any conflicting VPN or firewall software
* Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7072
```

What to do?

Comment: FTR I experienced this same problem when upgrading from Mac Catalina to Mac Big Sur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the tutorial you followed you have to make a new virtual network switch in the Hyper-V Manager with the type **External**. The author does not explain why the network switch has to be external, other than that this configuration is best for avoiding headaches with Minikube not working properly with other software.

For some reason the External type of the virtual network switch was the problem, instead of External type use the **Internal** type for your virtual network switch in the Hyper-V Manager. Then run the following command to delete the wrong configurated cluster and to clean up:

```
minikube delete
```

Now, re-run the create/launch command for your Minikube cluster with your internal virtual network switch:

```
minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Your Internal Virtual Switch"
```

Now you're all set with your new cluster when it finishes correctly!

Comment: `minikube start --hyperv-use-external-switch` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Fix On Azure VM in Windows Server 2019:

0. Check if minikube VM has an IP Address in Networking tab

   - If *NO* IP address and no DHCP is running in VM, then go to next step
1. Create [new InternalNAT switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization#set-up-internet-connectivity-for-the-guest-virtual-machine):

Powershell:

```
New-VMSwitch -Name "InternalNAT" -SwitchType Internal 

Get-NetAdapter
# Take note of the "ifIndex" for the virtual switch you just created, assuming 13

New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.0.1 -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceIndex 13

New-NetNat -Name "InternalNat" -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 192.168.0.0/24
```

2. Create DHCP Server

- Create new scope for 192.168.*.* (or any range, note down this range)

3. Delete and Re-create minikube and use "InternalNat" switch

```
minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "InternalNAT"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `minikube start --hyperv-use-external-switch` instead!

Answer (score 0):

Requirements
64-bit versions of Windows 10 Enterprise, Pro, or Education (system requirements)
Hyper-V enabled
Enabling Hyper-V
Open a PowerShell console as Administrator, and run the following command:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

If Hyper-V was not previously active, you will need to reboot.

Usage

```
minikube start --driver=hyperv
```

To make hyperv the default driver:

```
minikube config set driver hyperv
```

Spec